# Android Studio, Layout Will Not Display on Emulator

Tags: android, xml

I just downloaded the new Android Studio Application and I started the training on their website. I'm on "Building your first Android App" and the "Building a simple user interface" part of it. However, the files they told me to edit was activity_my.xml, but everything was pointing to another file in my layout called content_my.xml. So I edited that file instead and got the design working on it, however when I click back to activity_my.xml, the design is not there at all.

Code for activity_my.xml (this was given to me I did not edit it at all)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"    
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"  
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" 
  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_my" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

code for content_my.xml (What I edited according to the training)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"  />
```

For the strings, I have also done what the training had asked:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My First App</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
```

After I run the app using the emulator I would get this:

[Doesn't run the correct design as viewed on the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG2g9.png)

I was supposed to get this:

[Correct view for emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nlGe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the ActionBar reserves room and pushes content down accordingly, but the new AppBarLayout matched with a ToolBar doesn't do this. This means the other layouts need to be told of the AppBarLayout's existance to correctly position themselves.
Your layout isn't doing this, so the EditText and Button are being hidden by the AppBarLayout.

Add this to your LinearLayout in content_my.xml

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

I am 99.9% sure this code is in the default activity when a new project is created, so you must've deleted it when editing the file.

The standard activity layout is split into 2 parts by default now (you can easily change this back by just copying the contents of content_my.xml into activity_my.xml if you wanted). The guide you're reading is most likely a bit outdated.

Comment: +1 thanks that did the trick. Sorry I'm new at this, so the problem was the new AppBarLayout? Specifically which part of the code was making this not work? And as for your solution, can you explain a bit about what it is actually doing to my LinearLayout? Also do you know a good website besides the android one that explains in detail how to start builing a first app. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Normally the ActionBar reserves room and pushes content down accordingly, but the new AppBarLayout matched with a ToolBar doesn't do this. This means the other layouts need to be told of the AppBarLayout's existance to correctly position themselves.
Your layout isn't doing this, so the EditText and Button are being hidden by the AppBarLayout.

Add this to your LinearLayout in content_my.xml